# Find all the whole solutions of the equation: $15x+12y+30z=24$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

**Find all the whole solutions of the equation: $15x+12y+30z=24$**

I know there is a very similar post on this that is the following: [Prove that the Diophantine equation $ax+by+cz=e$ has a solution if and only if $(a,b,c)\mid e$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514589/prove-that-the-diophantine-equation-axbycz-e-has-a-solution-if-and-only-if) And I also know that $mcd(15,12,30)=3$ with which one could reduce this to the problem $5x+4y+10z=8$ but I do not know how to reach a solution or find all the solutions, could someone help me please? Thank you very much

Comment: obviously, there is infinite number of solutions. Are there any restrictions on $x$, $y$ and $z$?

Comment: @Vasya Whole numbers.

Comment: Well, in case if you need to find "a" solution, $x$ cannot be odd (why?)

Comment: @Vasya $x,y,z\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @imranfat Because if $x$ were odd then $5x$ would be odd and so $5x+12y+30z$ would be odd?

Comment: @Nash and that would spark trouble because 8 is....even

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions of the form $(2a, 2, -a)$

Answer (score 1):

Denote  $y = 3u-5v$ and $z = 2v-u$ so that the equation reduces to $$15x+12(3u-5v)+30(2v-u)=24$$
$$ \Rightarrow 5x+2u=8$$
Solving gives infinite solutions, namely $x=2-2k$ and $u=5k-1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Can you find something similar to work out $y$ and $z$?

Comment: How can I find something similar that works for $y$ and $z$?

Comment: By finding expressions involving $y$ and $z$ which reduces the equation like i did above - it's just guess work finding the right one